# Select and "ol" html tag with Watir Webdriver

Tags: selenium, watir

I want to create a for loop to get the text from several lis with watir.

Here's is the HTML I'm trying to scrape

```
<ol class="shared-connections">
 <li class="small-result">
  <a class="img-link" href="http://www.google.com"></a>    
 </li>
 <li class="small-result">
  <a class="img-link" href="http://www.google.com"></a>    
 </li>
</ol>
```

I'm tring to get the href value in the links with a loop, but I can't get the loop to initiate with this code:

```
@browser.ol(class: "shared-connections").lis(class: "small-result").each do |connection|
p "is this working?"
end
```

The "ol" tag prevents the loop from working and gives me this error:

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-webdriver-0.9.1/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:536:in `assert_element_found': unable to locate element, using {:class=>"shared-connections", :tag_name=>"ol"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

Any idea how to get "ol" to work with Watir? Thanks!

Comment: `ol` tags work fine in Watir. The error says it can't find an `ol` tag with the class `shared-connections`. Verify that you are on the right page and not inside an iframe.

Comment: You can use `#exists?` and `#visible?` in this scenario to help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't open proper page via code.

Code is working well. I created file with code you provided

in irb:

`pp File.readlines('a.html')`

```
["<ol class=\"shared-connections\">",    
 " <li class=\"small-result\">,    
 "  <a class=\"img-link\" href=\"http://www.google.com\"></a>,    
 " </li>",    
 " <li class=\"small-result\">,    
 "  <a class=\"img-link\" href=\"http://www.google.com\"></a>",        
 " </li>",    
 "</ol>"]
```

Then

```
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
b.goto 'file://' + Dir.pwd + '/a.html'

b.ol(class: "shared-connections").lis(class: "small-result").each do |connection|
  p "is this working?"
end
"is this working?"
"is this working?"
=> [#<Watir::LI:0x604055b6f2097db6 located=false selector={element: (webdriver element)}>, #<Watir::LI:0x..f5826cdc74313e1a located=false selector={element: (webdriver element)}>]
```

You can ensure about this with `@browser.html`